# unable to resolve class MavenDeployment after updating the gradle wrapper

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, maven-plugin

Android Studio offered me to update the gradle wrapper and I accepted.

After the update process it updated the wrapper to the version 7.0.2.

Now I'm getting the following error on my project:

```
unable to resolve class MavenDeployment 
        @ line 30, column 34.
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }
        ^
        1 error
```

It is a library project and I'm using the following guide (and script) for publishing it on MavenCentral: [simple library publishing with Gradle](https://zserge.com/posts/gradle-maven-publish/)

It seems it is no longer resolving the class **MavenDeployment** from the maven plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Exatly at this point on the script:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
            repositories {
                    mavenDeployer {
                            beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }
...
```

I'm not a gradle expert. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally identified the problem: The old maven plugin is deprecated in the new gradle versions.

If you are experiencing this error you need to rewrite your script to use [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Comment: can you share your 'maven.gradle' file in which you fixed this bug.

Comment: I am using the new maven-publish plugin, but I am still getting the same error.   Would be helpful to know what the new rewritten script looks like.   Maven pages show the old one.

Comment: What do you mean by old maven plugin?

Comment: @Addev, can you please share the changes you made?

Comment: Well... it's deprecated... that's usually not a build **error**. Would be nice if the build could complete still

Comment: Hi everyone. Any pointer to the 'maven.gradle' file?
I'm stuck.

Answer (score -1):

This might be because you're running your project on two platforms together.
As in my case, I was building the project in android studio and xcode at the same time.
Close one and delete the derived data and rebuild.